# Fit the text in the button control on resize by changing Fontsize dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, button, resize

I have a application in which the text of different length is set on the button every 5 seconds.
How do i resize the text to fit it in the button.
Also i need to resize the font on resizing the window.(my button size increases on resizing window as i have used dock property on it.

The following is the code i used to do it, but its not working very fine when the text length is 2 or less.(the text pops a bit out of the control)

```
public static void FitControlFont(Control control)
        {
            if (control.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                Font currentFont = control.Font;
                Graphics graphics = control.CreateGraphics();
                SizeF newSize = graphics.MeasureString(control.Text, control.Font);
                graphics.Dispose();

                float factorX = control.Width / newSize.Width;
                float factorY = control.Height / newSize.Height;
                float factor = factorX > factorY ? factorY : factorX;
                if (control.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    control.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { control.Font = new Font(currentFont.Name, currentFont.SizeInPoints * factor); }));
                }
                else
                {
                    control.Font = new Font(currentFont.Name, currentFont.SizeInPoints * factor);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (Exceptions.IsCritical(ex))
                {
                    throw;
                }

                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the button's `autosize` property to true, this will make it's width fit to content.

Concerning changing the font, you can handle the SizeChanged of the button ( since you set it's dock property) and determine some ratio for the font relative to the form's height :

```
private void button1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     button1.Font = new Font(button1.Font.FontFamily, this.Size.Height / 10) ;
}
```

Comment: autosize = true dosent make sence in my application as the size depends on the size of the window as i have used dock property.

Comment: You can fit width to text , but you can't fit text to width. Autosize property makes no sense if you set the dock property.

Comment: yes, but what i want here is to reduce or increase the font size dynamically so that it can fit correctly in the button.

Answer (score 0):

I improved the function a bit because in your example the `control.Width` and `newSize.Width` are integer, `control.Height` and `newSize.Height` are also integer, so when you calculate the form factors you get an integer result and cast it as float, which is not a good form factor (and can be zero crashing the newly created `Font`):

```
        public static void FitControlFont(Control control)
        {
            if (control.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                Font currentFont = control.Font;
                Graphics graphics = control.CreateGraphics();
                SizeF newSize = graphics.MeasureString(control.Text, control.Font);
                graphics.Dispose();

                float factorX = ((float)control.Width) / newSize.Width;
                float factorY = ((float)control.Height) / newSize.Height;
                float factor = factorX > factorY ? factorY : factorX;
                if (control.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    control.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { control.Font = new Font(currentFont.Name, currentFont.SizeInPoints * factor); }));
                }
                else
                {
                    control.Font = new Font(currentFont.Name, currentFont.SizeInPoints * factor);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (Exceptions.IsCritical(ex))
                {
                    throw;
                }

                return;
            }
        }
```